# Spring send user passwords in http request body. Storing passwords in java

Tags: java, node.js, spring, authentication, passwords

I created a node rest API using firebase to log in users. The body is a JSON with a username and password. How can I login users on my spring application and secure user passwords and not put it directly in the post request? This is how my API logs in a user I send it the JSON:

```
{
   email: test@test.com,
   password: 123456
}
```

In spring I can send that JSON to the API but I feel like saving a password in a model and sending it is not the proper way to go. How do I do this?

I've looked at spring security and I'm so confused. It encodes a password but my API doesn't know the encoded password? If someone can help me with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use a POST for this. You would use the authorization header and HTTPS for encryption. In regards to your API not knowing the encrypted password, that is ideal. You could have your spring application generate a token that could be linked to the account. Then you could use that token on the API to perform validation for requests. You can validate by sending a request from the API to the spring server to check if the token is valid.

Comment: But when I get the user password in the login form, I am saving the password in a User model so i think that is plaintext?

Comment: The authorization header uses Base64. Its also worth mentioning the input type for a password also has a specific type for passwords so its not visible to the eye.

Comment: Check the following link out; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login